# Basic Authentication failed in Windows server 2012 Using Java

Tags: java, httpurlconnection, basic-authentication

I am trying to connection my certificate service over windows server 2012. I have enabled Basic Authentication over server and I can access my service from browser providing user name and password. 
I am opening connection using `HttpURLConnection` in Java.
Connection is successful using following code.

```
static class MyAuthenticator extends Authenticator {
    public PasswordAuthentication getPasswordAuthentication() {
        System.out.println("trying to authenticate");
        return new PasswordAuthentication("user", "password".toCharArray());
    }
}

Authenticator.setDefault(new MyAuthenticator())
```

But I need to connect using following code and it gives me 401 error:

```
String encoding = Base64.encode("user:password".getBytes());
HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
connection.setRequestMethod("GET");
connection.setDoOutput(true);
connection.setRequestProperty  ("Authorization", "Basic " + encoding);
```

Any idea why I am getting 401.

Thanks,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Basic authentication for `Default Web Site` on `IIS Manager` was enabled but `Basic Authentication` for specific site was not enabled. By enabling `Basic Authentication` for specific Website resolved the issue.